# Can Google Sheets onFormSubmit trigger work with a Gravity Forms submission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gravityforms

Quite simply, when I receive a response from a Gravity Form, can I use Google Sheets onFormSubmit trigger to copy the newly submitted values to another sheet.

Other questions on this topic have not been answered.  Google searches have eaten up a lot of time and yielded no results.

Anyone out there who can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran some tests since I was not able to find any documentation either. The only thing that I was able to find in the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers) is this:

> “An installable form submit trigger runs when a user responds to a
> form. There are two versions of the form-submit trigger, one for
> Google Forms itself and one for Sheets if the form submits to a
> spreadsheet.”

Which makes me assume that the “form submit” only works with Google Forms. However, I was reading the documentation of [Gravity Forms](https://gravitymore.com/documentation/gravity-forms-google-spreadsheet-addon/,) and the step "HOW TO GET CLIENT ID AND CLIENT SECRET ID FROM GOOGLE DEVELOPERS CONSOLE" makes me believe that they are using Google Sheets API to makes changes on the Google Sheet.

So the best trigger to use for this situation is an `On change` trigger instead. Like this one:

[image: On change]

Since `On change` is a trigger that will fire when the spreadsheet's content or structure is changed. As mentioned in the same [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers).

The API changes are taken as a change of content or structure instead of an edition or a form submission.

Comment: Important to note that onChange will not fire from programmatical changes. They must be manual unfortunately.

Comment: I tested with API changes and it works for me. Using Google forms will not work. However, Gravity forms use Google Sheets API

Comment: I have added an onChange trigger to this project and it does trigger upon Gravity Forms submission.  Unfortunately, it also triggers with any other change to the sheet.  I guess a script that looks only at changes to the first column to which data from the form is written will help to prevent the trigger from running with any other change to the sheet.  Thank you @Giselle.